# jQuery/ajax help required

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have below list of links

```
<div id='list1'>
<a href='#1'>USA</a>
<a href='#2'>Canada</a>
<a href='#3'>France</a>
</div>

<div id='list2'>
<a href='#1'>Cars</a>
<a href='#2'>Houses</a>
<a href='#3'>Machines</a>
</div>
```

What I want to do is when a user click on USA then it(The USA link) gets bold. The user then click on any element in list 2. After clicking both the links, the values of selected element in link1 and link2 are passed to an ajax function. Can anyone please tell me about this.

Comment: What about if the user first clicks on a link in the second list and then one in the first?

Comment: Did you try anything so far? Maybe post a code snippet. Don't just expect others to do the work for you

Comment: Post a little bit of you javascript and we can help you

Comment: Alp I can make a button which trigger the ajax function then both the clicked links values will be submitted.

Comment: For others, I know how to get values of a multiple select box using .val() and id but I dont know how to get values from a href link. Any suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't check it, but you can use smth like that:

```
<div id='list1'>
<a href='#1'>USA</a>
<a href='#2'>Canada</a>
<a href='#3'>France</a>
</div>

<div id='list2'>
<a href='#1'>Cars</a>
<a href='#2'>Houses</a>
<a href='#3'>Machines</a>
</div>

<script>
     $(document).ready(function(){
          $('#list1 > a').click(function(){
               $('#list1 > a').attr('class', '');
               $(this).attr('class','selected');

               if ($('#list2 > a.selected').length > 0)
               {
                     $.post('post/submit/url', {'link1':$(this).attr("href"), 'link2':$('#list2 > a.selected').attr("href")}, function(data){
                          alert(data);
                     });
               }
          });

          $('#list2 > a').click(function(){
               $('#list2 > a').attr('class', '');
               $(this).attr('class','selected');

               if ($('#list1 > a.selected').length > 0)
               {
                     $.post('post/submit/url', {'link1':$('#list1 > a.selected').attr("href"), 'link2':$(this).attr("href")}, function(data){
                          alert(data);
                     });
               }
          });
     });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Do something like:
Create a hidden input element for storing selected country value,

```
$("#list1 a").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).addClass("blodAnchor");// may be font-weight bold in this class
  $("#selectedCountry").val('');
  $("#selectedCountry").val($(this).text());
});

//then
$("#list2 a").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var selectedVal = $(this).text() || "";
  var selectedCountry = $("#selectedCountry").val() || "";
  if(selectedCountry != "" && selectedVal != "") {
     $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       data: {country: selectedCountry, someVal : selectedVal},
       url: ".....",
       success: function(resp) {
          ........
       }
     });
  }
});
```